# Getting a null object reference error when navigating back to another frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop

I really need help, I've been stuck on this problem for the pass 2 days. I keep getting this error when navigating back to another frame!

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at product_fla::MainTimeline/frog_mcRelease()
```

the frog_mc keeps going onto another frame!! don't know whats wrong.

thanks

my code:

```
import flash.events.Event;

right_mc.visible=false; 
wrong_mc.visible=false;

var orig1X:Number=frog_mc.x;  
var orig1Y:Number=frog_mc.y;
var orig2X:Number=queen_mc.x;
var orig2Y:Number=queen_mc.y;
var orig3X:Number=apple_mc.x;
var orig3Y:Number=apple_mc.y; 

stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frog_mcRelease);

frog_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
frog_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, frog_mcRelease);
queen_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);   
queen_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, queen_mcRelease);   
apple_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);    
apple_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, apple_mcRelease);    

done_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkAnswers);    
reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);

frog_mc.buttonMode=true;    
queen_mc.buttonMode=true;    
apple_mc.buttonMode=true;

function dragTheObject(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target); 
    item.startDrag(); 
    var topPos:uint=this.numChildren-1; 
    this.setChildIndex(item, topPos);   
}  


function frog_mcRelease(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target); 
    item.stopDrag();       
    if (drop_frog.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) { 
        item.x=drop_frog.x; 
        item.y=drop_frog.y; 
    } else { 
       item.x=orig1X; 
       item.y=orig1Y; 
    } 
};    

function queen_mcRelease(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target); 
    item.stopDrag();   
    if (drop_queen.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) { 
        item.x=drop_queen.x; 
        item.y=drop_queen.y; 
    } else { 
        item.x=orig2X; 
        item.y=orig2Y; 
    } 
};    

function apple_mcRelease(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target); 
    item.stopDrag();   
    if (drop_apple.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) { 
        item.x=drop_apple.x; 
        item.y=drop_apple.y; 
    } else { 
        item.x=orig3X; 
        item.y=orig3Y; 
    } 
};  

function checkAnswers(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    if (drop_frog.hitTestPoint(frog_mc.x,frog_mc.y) && 
            drop_queen.hitTestPoint(queen_mc.x,queen_mc.y) && 
            drop_apple.hitTestPoint(apple_mc.x,apple_mc.y)) {
        wrong_mc.visible = false;
        right_mc.visible = true;
    } else {
        wrong_mc.visible = true;
        right_mc.visible = false;
    }
}

function reset(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    frog_mc.x=orig1X; 
    frog_mc.y=orig1Y;     
    queen_mc.x=orig2X; 
    queen_mc.y=orig2Y;
    apple_mc.x=orig3X; 
    apple_mc.y=orig3Y; 

    right_mc.visible=false; 
    wrong_mc.visible=false; 
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that it's erroring out because `drop_frog` does not exist?

Comment: drop_frog is my target when frog_mc drops it on

Comment: Yes, I gathered that from the code snippet. What I'm asking is whether  you are sure it exists within the scope of the code snippet?

Comment: Ok, so I'm guessing this code is on frame 1 of your main timeline, is it possible that `drop_frog` is on a different frame and therefore inaccessible to the code on frame 1? Also, I don't understand what you mean when you say that "`frog_mc` keeps going onto another frame"

Comment: Sorry, it's nearly impossible to troubleshoot a multi-framed script without access to the FLA.

Comment: You can post it to dropbox and post the link here. I have CS5, so be sure to downsave if you have a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target);

i think you should first create a new reference to the the MovieClip like this

var item:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

I think this should fix the problem

Comment: can you put a break point at                                         if (drop_frog.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y))  and see if drop_frog has a value or is it null?